# Create JSON using python with sequence key for LLD Zabbix discovery top mem process

Tags: python, json, zabbix

I try create JSON using python with sequence key for LLD Zabbix discovery top mem process

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import json

s = subprocess.Popen(["ps axho comm --sort -rss | head -5"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
service_states = s.read().splitlines()

count = 0
data = {"data":{}}
for i in service_states:
  count += 1
  key = "{#TOPMEMNAME" + str(count) + "}"
  data["data"][key] = i

json_data = json.dumps(data)
print(json_data)
```

Get JSON not accepted Zabbix (Below code):

```
{
  "data": {
    "{#TOPMEMNAME2}": "node",
    "{#TOPMEMNAME1}": "mongod",
    "{#TOPMEMNAME4}": "ffmpeg",
    "{#TOPMEMNAME3}": "kubelet",
    "{#TOPMEMNAME5}": "dockerd"
  }
}
```

Below code where Zabbix accepted JSON.

```
{
    "data": [{
            "{#TOPMEMNAME1}": "mongod"
        },
        {
            "{#TOPMEMNAME2}": "node"
        },
        {
            "{#TOPMEMNAME3}": "kubelet"
        },
        {
            "{#TOPMEMNAME4}": "ffmpeg"
        },
        {
            "{#TOPMEMNAME5}": "dockerd"
        }
    ]
}
```

How change python code for get JSON zabbix accepted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {"data":{}}
# should be changed to the line below
data = {"data":[]}

data["data"][key] = i
# should be changed to the line below
data["data"].append({key:i})
```